# Move all files in repository from one directory to another using ssh command line

Tags: linux, git, ssh, bitbucket

I have in digitalocean project which repository in **bitbucket**.

When I need to push something I write code in below.

firstly push all to bitbucket repository using **git bash**

1.checking changes `git status`

2.adding changes `git add -A`

3.and push `git push`

**Then using `putty` I push to digitalocean server.**

1.After opening putty I write `username`

2.After  `password`

3.Then going to directory cd /var/html/www/new

4.Then  `git pull origin master`

5.After I get an error something about permission denied and I write `sudo !!`

6.And my `password`

7.And **bitbucket** login `password`

And after this procedure I push to directory var/html/www/new

Question is:

> How I can move all files  from current **new** directory to **www**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you connected to the digital ocean server (with putty) and get the files to dircetory `var/html/www/new`, you can move the files with this command:

```
mv var/html/www/new/* var/html/www/
```

Now all the files will be in `var/html/www/`.

But better is just to pull the repo to this directory:

- Go to directory `cd /var/html/www`
- Then  `git pull origin master`